# Selenium: Get the contents of list elements as strings

Tags: python, selenium

My test web server returns the following HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu-id">
    <li><a href="">Pumpkins and Chocolate</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Click to Nowhere</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to use Selenium to print the contents of the `<li>` elements as strings. For example:

```
'<a href="">Pumpkins and Chocolate</a>'
'<a href="">Click to Nowhere</a>'
```

I tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
dropdown_list = self.browser.find_element_by_id('dropdown-menu-id')
items = dropdown_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    print "Item text: >%s<" % item.text
```

However, this prints out 2 empty strings. I am guessing this is probably due to the `<a>` tags that need to be accessed directly.

What is the correct way to print the contents of `<li>` as strings?

Comment: GetAttribute("innerHTML")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives following output:

```
Item text: >Pumpkins and Chocolate<
Item text: >Click to Nowhere<
```

If you want to get innerHTML change `item.text` to `item.get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

```
Item text: ><a href="">Pumpkins and Chocolate</a><
Item text: ><a href="">Click to Nowhere</a><
```

The reason why you got empty strings is because the web elements were **not visible** and `item.text` returns empty string in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use find_elements_by_xpath ('.//ul[@id="dropdown-menu-id"]/li/a')